# How to supply an Heuristic Objective solution to SCIP

Tags: scip, scipopt

I feel like I knew the answer for this question before but I am unable to recall it.

Is there a way to supply the SCIP program with a heuristic objective solution value?

Answer (score 1):

I finally found it!

We can do that by `SCIP_RETCODE SCIPsetObjlimit (SCIP* scip, SCIP_Real objlimit)`

https://www.scipopt.org/doc-4.0.0/html/group__GlobalProblemMethods.php#ga3fd90b931b38d2d8f344114babc2a67e